# How to find approximative value in file

Tags: python

I have file that look like this

```
    0   2.4
    1   2.6
    2   4.6
    3   5.7
    4   5.7
    5   6.7
```

and I would like to find let say the close value to 2.5 in row 2 in my file
in this case it 2.4  and 2.6  I can show my code

```
f=open('exemple.txt','r')
value = 2.5 
with f:
  for lines in f :
   if lines.split()[2]>= value or lines.split()[2]<= value 
      print( lines.split()[2])
      break
```

the code dont work but I am suppose to have as results 2.4  and 2.6 
Thanks

Comment: You have to store the minimum difference while you iterate and store the value that produces that difference, at the end you'll get the closest value.

Comment: hmm you mean I creat an array and store the difference

Comment: Your _row 2_ only has 1 value: 4.6 (according to your column 1). There is no 2.3 _anywhere_ in your file. The closest over all values of _column 2_ is either 2.4 or 2.6 which both differ by 0.1 - Your question is unclear.

Comment: @PatrickArtner that what I am looking for the closest value  to 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I'd do it, there's probably a better way to do it.

```
with open('untitled.txt','r') as f:
    x = [float(i.strip().split()[-1]) for i in  f.readlines()]
value = 2.5

y = [abs(i - value) for i in x]
out = [x[j] for j in [i for i,v in enumerate(y) if v == min(y)]]

out
> [2.4, 2.6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to iterate through the list, and keep the value with the minimal difference from `value`.

```
min_diff = 9999 # some difference that will surly be bigger than every diff.
value = 2.5
closest = 0
with open('example.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        v = line.split()[2]
        diff = abs(v - value)
        if diff < min_diff:
            min_diff = diff
            closest = v
print(closest)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I mean is something like below:

```
f=open('exemple.txt','r')
value = 2.5 
closestValue = None
minDiff = sys.maxsize # choose this value according to your problem
with f:
  for lines in f :
   curDiff = abs(int(line.split()[2]) - value)
   if (curDiff < minDiff):
        minDiff = curDiff
        closestValue = int(line.split()[2])
print(closestValue)
```